# CopyFromRecordset Returning Strange Characters

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, sql-server-2008, adodb

I have the following code below:

```
Function downloadsqltoexcel(conn As ADODB.Connection, sSQL As String, exceldestinationrangename As String, sqltablename As String, bDownload As Boolean, Optional ws As Worksheet) As Variant

'================================================================================================================================
'== Procedure Name: downloadsqltoexcel
'== Purpose: downloads SQL table data (or query data) to Excel named range or grabs a specific value from an SQL table
'== Notes: ensure that SQL table or query name and Excel named range are identical
'================================================================================================================================

Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DestinationRange As Range

With rsPubs

    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .Open sSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    If bDownload Then 'if download switch is on, dump into Excel named range

        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Set DestinationRange = Range(exceldestinationrangename)
        Else
            Set DestinationRange = ws.Range(exceldestinationrangename)
        End If

        With DestinationRange
            .ClearContents
            .CopyFromRecordset rsPubs
        End With

   .... more code follows, but not relevant
```

The code itself executes well. However, the `.CopyFromRecordset rsPubs` line returns very strange character data when I point to newly created Prod SQLServer database, which was copied directly from QA database in SQLServer as well.. When I say very strange, I mean like blank spaces mixed with Japanese style characters or some font set that I don't even recognize.

`rsPubs` returns exact record count as expected, so I know i am getting results I  want. Also confirmed that data is written into SQLServer DB as needed.

Any ideas how to fix it so values return as expected from call to Prod SQLServer DB?

Comment: Is your `exceldestinationrangename` a single cell or a multi-cell range? If I recall correctly, the range needs to be the top left cell *only*.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - Thanks, but that is not the issue. The range is single cell. Also, as my question states this is running perfectly when pointed to QA DB.

Comment: What do you get if you loop through the recordet and output to the immediate window? Same thing?

Comment: @Absinthe - It's been a while, but I believe the immediate window showed the correct results for each record when I looped through it. I ended up doing just that in my final solution (but never answered this question as it went out of my mind). Thanks for comment. Now I can clean this question up and provide a sustainable answer).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Sorry, didn't notice the post date, was just going through the unanswered section. For future reference I was going to suggest looking at the text encoding of the table. Glad you worked around the problem.

Comment: @Absinthe - Thanks for that suggestion too. I was thinking of that route, but since it's a production table and would require the db team to look into and make possible changes we we're trying to avoid that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looping through the recordset and placing each value one-by-one. That said, the array answer provided probably will work faster for large data sets. At the time, this fit my needs and worked.

```
If bDownload Then 'if download switch is on, dump into Excel named range

            If ws Is Nothing Then
                Set DestinationRange = Range(exceldestinationrangename)
            Else
                Set DestinationRange = ws.Range(exceldestinationrangename)
            End If

            r = 0

            DestinationRange.ClearContents
            '.CopyFromRecordset rsPubs 'this is breaking on PDLOBList download (last column not showing up) 'PAQPT-488

            If .RecordCount > 0 Then
                .MoveFirst
                Do Until .EOF
                    For c = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                        DestinationRange.Offset(r, c).value = .Fields(c)
                    Next
                    .MoveNext
                    r = r + 1
                Loop
```

*(I left out the rest of the `if` blocks as they are not relevant to this answer.)*

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem too and I strongly suspect the number of records returned in your RecordSet is quite large. Therefore, `CopyFromRecordSet` is not working.

I would suggest using the follwoing approach:

1. Populating a 2-D Array in VBA with the RecordSet data.

   Dim arr as Variant
   arr=rs.GetRows()
   rs.close
   conn.close
2. Transpose the Array (Since this results into an inverted Array)

   arr=Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
3. Once, the Array is transposed, you can write the Array to the worksheet Range.

   testWS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1) + 1, UBound(arr, 2)

This worked for me. Hope that works for you well! 
Happy coding!